# Missing argument 1 for function error

Tags: php, drupal, warnings

Warning: Missing argument 1 for function abc()

```
 function ort_view_menu() { 
      $items['thick_box_view'] = array( 
        'title' => 'Viewed Details', 
        'description' => 'g a report', 
        'page callback' => 'abc', 
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
        'access callback' => TRUE, 
       ); 

return $items;
}
         function abc($nid) { 
         $rows = array();
    $node = node_load($nid);
```

Is the error caused due to $nid used in the function ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, The call to the function `abc` does not supply the required argument `$nid` needed in the function.

Comment: how can I supply the value $nid in hook_menu ?

Comment: Post your full code from where are you calling the function `abc`?

Comment: abc is called in hook_menu()

Comment: still not clear? where is this `hook_menu()`?

Comment: function ort_view_menu() is the function where u can see the page callback is 'abc'

Comment: also check the edited question

Answer (score 3):

If you don't always need this parameter you could change it like this

```
function abc($nid=''){
 ...
}
```